# HTTP 500.19 - Wrong config file path

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to run my project is Visual Studio 15 but receive the following error:

[image: error]

I know for a fact the config file path is wrong, but my question is how do I change it?

Comment: how do you know its wrong? is this iis express?

Comment: It's the wrong hard drive path for a start, it's pointing to an old hard drive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change path as like below.

```
C:\Users\xxx\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config in the following way -
<configuration>
  <system.applicationHost>
    <sites>
      <site name="TestWebSite">
        <application path="/">
           <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\myWork\Dev\" />
```

Please change path only inside physical Path tag.

If you have hosted your application in network drive, please try to move it on local drive.

Comment: additionally if you don't want to go for change in apphostconfig file, you can try below.

Right click Web Project -> Web -> Project Url > (i.e. 'localhost:60595') 
Here increment port number which will create a new entry in that file.